# For a chiral superfield, $\overline{D}^2 D^2 \Phi = 16 \partial^2 \Phi$

Tags: supersymmetry

When looking for the derivation of the Kahler potential, generally is assumed the following idendity:

For a Chiral superfield $\Phi$, we have

$$\overline{D}^2 D^2 \Phi = 16 \partial^2 \Phi$$

But before proceed, i can't realize how this is true! I tried to show it by brutal hand, that is, writing all the terms and the derivatives. But i was not succesfull in any way to derive it. So, i tried to use the integral trick

$$D^2 = - 4 \int d^2 \theta$$

This implies (assuming $\Phi = \theta^2 (\overline{\theta})^2 \partial^2 \phi + ...$),

$$\overline{D}^2 D^2 \Phi = 16 \int d^2\overline{\theta} d^2 \theta \left (\theta^2 (\overline{\theta})^2 \partial^2 \phi + (...) \right ) = 16 \partial^2 \phi $$

But $\partial^2 \Phi \neq \partial^2 \phi$, so i didn't really show anything. I think i am missing something, or maybe misinterpretating something, because it seems really an obvious statement during the text, but i can't prove it.

Comment: Either you or whatever text you are reading from is using sloppy notation. If $D^2$ is truly a Grassmannian integral over $\theta$ (I am taking your word for this), then the result of that integral cannot possibly depend on $\theta$. On the other hand, the superfield $\Phi$ depends on $\theta$, so your starting equation itself is untrue.

Comment: @Prahar But it seems a common result used in the area. It is used in 

"Introduction to supersymmetry and supergravity (P. West), pg 100", also

"Introduction to AdS/CFT (H. Nastase), pg 63"

Comment: sorry I couldn't find this equation on page 63 of Nastase. Could you point out the exact equation?

Comment: @Prahar Oh yes, of course. 3.108

Comment: OK, based on equation (3.102) of the book (I was previously looking at the arXiv article, so I couldn't find it), your integral identity is false. What is true is that $- 4 \int d^2 \theta = D^2 |_{\theta = {\bar \theta} = 0}$. You will have to work out the derivative action from its definition in equation (3.91)

Comment: @Prahar Oh yes, i have tried to computed this identity directly by using 3.91 (using pure hand, basically), but i haven't suceed. I've got too many terms, and the chances that i have done something wrong is just too big. Can i still use this integral (the one you have quoted) to prove this identity? I mean, at the end of the day, if i use the "integral method", the proof will end something like $\overline{D}^2 D^2 \bigg |_{\theta=\overline{\theta}=0} \Phi = \partial^2 \Phi$ ? But this is not the original identity

Comment: you cannot. The integral identity only holds after you set $\theta = {\bar \theta} = 0$ on both sides. What you have managed to prove is ${\bar D}^2 D^2 \Phi |_{\theta = {\bar \theta} = 0} = 16 \partial^2 \phi$. This is absolutely correct as an identity, but not what you wanted to prove. You have to go through the actual calculation by hand (SUGRA is calculationally very (extremely!) intense but since you chose to study this, you have to get your hands wet).